# How to define a null-coalescing operator for Twig?

Tags: php, twig

I want to define the null-coalescing operator for Twig as per [this RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary). That is to say I should be able to write an expression like

```
{{ x ?? y ?? 5 }}
```

Which would return `x` if it's defined and non-null, otherwise `y` if it's defined and non-null, otherwise 5.

This should *not* error if `strict_variables` is enabled.

I've started the implementation, but I don't know enough about the internals of Twig to complete it.

We can define the operator with an extension:

```
class Core extends \Twig_Extension {

    public function getName() {
        return 'nullcoalesce';
    }

    public function getOperators() {
        return [
            [], // I *think* these are where the unary operators go...?
            [
                '??' => array('precedence' => 20, 'class' => NullCoalesce::class, 'associativity' => \Twig_ExpressionParser::OPERATOR_LEFT),
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

And then here's the operator:

```
class NullCoalesce extends \Twig_Node_Expression_Binary
{
    public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
    {
        // ???
    }

    public function operator(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
    {
        // ???
    }
}
```

How can I fill in those methods to get the desired result?

Comment: It is worth noting that Twig has support for the [null coalescing operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators), though I can't find in the changelog when it was added.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 It was added just recently (1.24.0 (2016-01-25)), after I finished adding this. And it actually [doesn't work as well](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1979) as my implementation it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Twig files are compiled to PHP code, you need to tell Twig how to convert your new operator in PHP:

```
public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
{
    // gives random variable name
    $var = $compiler->getVarName();

    // compiles: (($var = left) !== NULL ? $var : right)
    $compiler
       ->raw(sprintf('(($%s = ', $var))
       ->subcompile($this->getNode('left'))
       ->raw(sprintf(') !== NULL ? $%s : ', $var))
       ->subcompile($this->getNode('right'))
       ->raw(sprintf(')'))
    ;
}

public function operator(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
{
    return $compiler->raw('');
}
```

Documentation is a bit poor about the subject, but there are lots of existing operators in `lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Binary` if somebody requires more samples.

---

About your comment on the way operators are stored in the extension, you're right. If you look at the `initExtension` method of Twig's Environment.php, you'll see:

```
        $this->unaryOperators = array_merge($this->unaryOperators, $operators[0]);
        $this->binaryOperators = array_merge($this->binaryOperators, $operators[1]);
```

It would have been easier to have 2 methods in the extension, `getUnaryOperators` and `getBinaryOperators` but anyway, that's on the doc so we can't blame them for this :-).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. This works great if `strict_variables` is disabled, but still throws an exception otherwise. The `default` filter and `defined` test are the only two things I know of that bypass this, but neither of them are operators and they both work a bit differently and use deprecated interfaces. I'm going to copy a bit of code out of there and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: That's true, for undefined variables, you'll get an exception if `strict_variables` is enabled. I guess we can do a workaround by using something like `$this->getNode('left')->setAttribute('ignore_strict_check', true);`. Don't have the Twig source here, but you might want to try.

Comment: That seems to work for simple cases like `{{ x ?? 1 }}` but not `{{ x ?? y ?? 1 }}`.... unless I use right associativity. I wonder if that'll cause weirdness.

Comment: No weirdness here, as if `x` is used later, it will be redefined in another node. You do the exception only around your operator.